# Difference between LSTMCell and MinimalRNNCell

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When I look up the implementation of LSTMCell and MinimalRNNCell in the following link, I found that they are different, anyone knows the reason, and if i want to create my own lstm cell, I should follow the instruction of LSTMCell or MinimalRNNCell ? And if the answer is LSTMCell, then what is the functionality of MinimalRNNCell ?

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/20b840fa4d8e62674a9090e34fc9943a4ecd04ec/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2415

codes for LSTMCell:

```
def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
    h_tm1 = states[0]  # previous memory state
    c_tm1 = states[1]  # previous carry state

    dp_mask = self.get_dropout_mask_for_cell(inputs, training, count=4)
    rec_dp_mask = self.get_recurrent_dropout_mask_for_cell(h_tm1, training, count=4)

    if self.implementation == 1:
        if 0 < self.dropout < 1.:
            inputs_i = inputs * dp_mask[0]
            inputs_f = inputs * dp_mask[1]
            inputs_c = inputs * dp_mask[2]
            inputs_o = inputs * dp_mask[3]
        else:
            inputs_i = inputs
            inputs_f = inputs
            inputs_c = inputs
            inputs_o = inputs
        k_i, k_f, k_c, k_o = tf.split(self.kernel, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)
        x_i = backend.dot(inputs_i, k_i)
        x_f = backend.dot(inputs_f, k_f)
        x_c = backend.dot(inputs_c, k_c)
        x_o = backend.dot(inputs_o, k_o)
        if self.use_bias:
            b_i, b_f, b_c, b_o = tf.split(self.bias, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=0)
            x_i = backend.bias_add(x_i, b_i)
            x_f = backend.bias_add(x_f, b_f)
            x_c = backend.bias_add(x_c, b_c)
            x_o = backend.bias_add(x_o, b_o)

        if 0 < self.recurrent_dropout < 1.:
            h_tm1_i = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[0]
            h_tm1_f = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[1]
            h_tm1_c = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[2]
            h_tm1_o = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[3]
        else:
            h_tm1_i = h_tm1
            h_tm1_f = h_tm1
            h_tm1_c = h_tm1
            h_tm1_o = h_tm1
        x = (x_i, x_f, x_c, x_o)
        h_tm1 = (h_tm1_i, h_tm1_f, h_tm1_c, h_tm1_o)
        c, o = self._compute_carry_and_output(x, h_tm1, c_tm1)
    else:
        if 0. < self.dropout < 1.:
            inputs = inputs * dp_mask[0]
        z = backend.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        z += backend.dot(h_tm1, self.recurrent_kernel)
        if self.use_bias:
            z = backend.bias_add(z, self.bias)

        z = tf.split(z, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)
        c, o = self._compute_carry_and_output_fused(z, c_tm1)

    h = o * self.activation(c)
    return h, [h, c]
```

codes for MinimalRNNCell:

```
def call(self, inputs, states):
    prev_output = states[0]
    h = backend.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
    output = h + backend.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
    return output, [output]
```

Answer (score 0):

MinimalRNNCell is implemented for RNN cell, which has no long term dependency (cell state) as what is known as RNN; while LSTMCell is implemented for the basic unit LSTM cell, and it has the long term (cell state) and short term (hidden state) dependencies.